# How is possible to modify manually occupancy grid cells on a map?

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, gmapping, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the point is that during the mapping with a mobile robot I will get a set of coordinates during the process. I was wondering, how is possible to modify the values of the occupancy grid cells nearby such coordinates.

For instance, these coordinates would represent objects that I don't want them in the map but they have been detected and stored in the map during the gmapping process as obstacles. I am not sure how to approach, whether using a real-time processing or post-processing.

Is there any available tool that can achieve something similar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316754/how-is-possible-to-modify-manually-occupancy-grid-cells-on-a-map?/) by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-27**:
Can you be more specific about what you exaclty want to achieve please ? How will you use your modified occupancy grid ?

> I will get a set of coordinates during the process

How will you get them ?

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-02-27**:
An object detector implementation with a depth camera will provide the coordinates of certain objects. See for instance [find_object](http://wiki.ros.org/find_object_2d). So when the robot detects these certain objects while gmapping, I'd like to remove them from the map (e.g. a paper bin).

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-27**:
And by saying " remove them from the map" you mean clear the cell value at the pose of the object (i.e. from 100=obstacle to 0=free) to get a map with only the walls, do I understand your issue correctly  ?

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-02-27**:
Indeed, that's what exactly what I wanted to express.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-27**:
Alsoo one last precision please : how will this new occupancy grid be used ? During the gmapping process or you just want to build a map without objects inside (meaning that you wouldn't have to "reinject" your occupancy grid in the mapping process)

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-02-28**:
The idea would be to "remove" from the occupancy grid little areas around the markers during gmapping process if possible, that is to build a map without objects inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you want to achieve could be tricky. From my understanding of the pakage `find_object` (and correct me if I'm wrong, it's a key point), you will be able to get the position of some objects, it will be only one poisition but not the edges of this object. That means that you would know in the occupancy grid the area where you need to change the cells data, but not the exact pose of each cells.

With that in mind, you will have to find the edges of an object given its position.

First, you will need to get the occupancy grid from gmapping. To create your new map I would use two occupancy grid : one occupancy grid will be your objects free map, I'll call it `cleared_map`,and the other one would be used to create the previous one, I'll call it `history_map`.

**Why two occupancy grids ?**

The idea is to use the data from gmapping to create a new map. The data from the topic `map` is an array containing the value of each cells of your map. With `gmapping` the cells have three values :

- -1 : UNKNOWN.
- 0 : FREE.
- 100 : OCCUPIED.

Your goal is to create a new map by replacing the values of the cells at the pose of an object from `100` to `0`, that would remove the objects from the map. You need to have another occupancy grid to save the history of your objects that have been removed. This occupancy grid would have cells with intermediate values at the pose of the objects (I'll suggest `50` but anything different than 0, -1 or 100 would be fine). This occupancy grid will be constantly overwritten (meaning the value of each cells) by the occupancy grid from gmapping to always have the updated map, unless the cells have the value `50`. By doing so you won't have to deal with the same object each time. Without `history_map`, you wouldn't know which cell needs to be overwritten or not and you would do the same calculations over and over.

Then you will have to remove the objects and you'll be able to create the `cleared_map` by changing every cells of `histroy_map` from the value `50` to `0`.

**Delete your objects**

You now have your `history_map`, the goal is now to find which cells will be set at the value `50`. You do have the pose of your objects. To work from a pose with an occupancy grid you first need to convert this pose to an index to get the corresponding cell.

Now here's the tricky part. You have to find all the cells corresponding to your object. You can assume that an object in map is always a group of cells at the value `-1` and the edges at `100` (because `gmapping` can't see inside objects so the cells are always unknown). For a cylindric paper bin as you used this example the map data should be something like that :

```
0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0    100   100    0     0
0    100   -1    -1    100    0
0    100   -1    -1    100    0
0     0    100   100    0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0
```

You may assume that the position given by `find_object` is the center of an object so the cell would always have the value `-1`. You need to check all the neighbor cells of the cell you get from the object pose having the value `-1` until you find a neighbor with the value `100`. Once you get the list of all the cells at the object pose you can change their value to `50` :

```
0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     50    50    0     0
0     50    50    50    50    0
0     50    50    50    50    0
0     0     50    50    0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now you have your `history_map` with an object detected, you just have to copy the occupancy grid and replace the `50` by `0` to get your `cleared_map`.

Note : I couldn't find ros packages doing that but you can probably identify objects using openCV, that would be more precize and easier than working direclty with the occupancy grid data. Moreover, if my first assumption about the coordinates of the objects being only one pose is wrong and you do have the edges, then the last part is trivial.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-02-28**:
I do really find your answer very helpful indeed. I thought about the idea of creating an additional occupancy grid besides the map but I didn't think about having an auxiliar map in order to avoid redundant computations. I will research about the implementation of your approach, many thanks Delb.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-28**:
Glad it helps. Can you also tell me what is the otput of `find_object` ? Is it just one pose for an object or all the edges of the objects ?

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-02-28**:
It returns the transformations of the detections, i.e., the pose. Regardless what package I use, the procedure will be the same. I can also use packages more sophisticated based on deep learning instead.